# how to Generate code from clang::ASTContext

Tags: c++, llvm, clang, libclang

I need a sample code to learn how to Generate C++ Code from clang::ASTContext.

I created ast from c++ code and I made some changes in AST and now I want to Generate Code again.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use **Stmt** class's print method to generate code from a ast.

```
virtual bool VisitStmt(Stmt *st){
    std::string SStr;
    llvm::raw_string_ostream S(SStr);
    st->printPretty(S, nullptr, PrintingPolicy(LangOptions()));
    const std::string &Str = S.str();
    llvm::errs() << "---------begin----------\n";
    llvm::errs() << Str << "\n";
    llvm::errs() << "---------end----------\n";
}
```